# Why is my sprite stuck in the same position and will not move?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   def __init__(self, Team, Position):
       super().__init__()
       self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 800))


       self.red = (255, 0, 0)
       self.blue = (0, 0, 255)

       self.PlayerHolder = []
       self.Team = Team
       self.Position = Position
       self.CurrentPosition = ""
       
       # Player
       self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 20])
       self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

   def DrawPlayerShape(self, co_ordinate, colouropt):
       self.CurrentPosition = co_ordinate

       # Player's shape as a sprite
       self.image.fill(colour)
       self.rect.center = co_ordinate

   def MovePlayerForward(self, x, y):
       speed = self.Pace
       curr_x, curr_y = self.CurrentPosition
       curr_x += x
       curr_y += y
       st1.DrawPlayerShape((curr_x, curr_y), 'R')

class Button:
   def __init__(self, Title, x, y):
       self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 800))
       self.Title = Title
       self.Colour = (255, 255, 255)
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.Shape = pygame.Rect((self.x, self.y), (200, 100))

   def Draw(self):
       pygame.draw.rect(self.window, self.Colour, self.Shape)
       text_type = pygame.font.SysFont('arialunicode', 18).render(self.Title, True, (
    0, 0, 0))
       self.window.blit(text_type, self.Shape)
       # Checks if the buttons have been pressed to begin their function
       self.ClickCheck()

   def ClickCheck(self):
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if self.Shape.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            self.Colour = (80, 80, 80)
            if self.Title == 'Attacking':
                self.Attacking()
            elif self.Title == 'Defending':
                self.Defending()
            elif self.Title == 'Balanced':
                self.Balanced()
        else:
            self.Colour = (255, 255, 255)

def Attacking(self):
    pass

def Defending(self):
    plyer.st1.MovePlayerForward(0, 10)

def Balanced(self):
    pass

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.width = 1280
        self.height = 800
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 800))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Football Simulator")
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    def BuildWindow(self):
        # Builds the GUI
        self.window.fill((50, 50, 50))
        attacking_button.Draw()
        defensive_button.Draw()
        balance_button.Draw()
        self.BuildTeams()

    def BuildTeams(self):
        st1.DrawPlayerShape((630, 375), self.colour1)
    

    def Running(self):
        # Allows the window to stay open
        running = True
        while running:
            for events in pygame.event.get():
                if events.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
                    pygame.quit()

            self.BuildWindow()
            plyer.Players.draw(self.window)
            # Updating the window continuously
            pygame.display.flip()


st = Player('Arsenal', 'ST')
attacking_button = Button_tactics.Button('Attacking', 0, 100)
defensive_button = Button_tactics.Button('Defending', 0, 500)
balance_button = Button_tactics.Button('Balanced', 0, 300)
Players = pygame.sprite.Group()
Players.add(st1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    game.Running()
else:
     pass
```

When I press the defensive button, the player is meant to move. However, when I press the button, it remains frozen and is unable to move in any direction. Is this due to the while loop in the Game Class. I have tried to put the BuildTeam function outside of the loop, however this does not work either. Why is the sprite frozen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you call `self.BuildTeams()` in `BuildWindow`. This method resets the player to its initial position. Call `self.BuildTeams()` before the application loop, but not in `BuildWindow`:

```py
class Game:
    # [...]

    def BuildWindow(self):
        # Builds the GUI
        self.window.fill((50, 50, 50))
        attacking_button.Draw()
        defensive_button.Draw()
        balance_button.Draw()
        #self.BuildTeams()                   <--- DELETE

    # [...]

    def Running(self):
        self.BuildTeams()                  # <--- INSERT
        # Allows the window to stay open
        running = True
        while running:
            for events in pygame.event.get():
                if events.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
                    pygame.quit()

            self.BuildWindow()
            plyer.Players.draw(self.window)
            # Updating the window continuously
            pygame.display.flip()
```